# Confused on type issue with Contains and Dictionary / [String:String]

Tags: swift

Using Swift 2.x

I'm struggling with using Contains with two arrays of dictionaries.  I keep getting the following exception, but I'm not entirely sure why:

```
 "Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected 
 argument type '@noescape ([String : String]) throws -> Bool'"
```

Code:

```
 var d1: [[String:String]] = [["k1": "v1"], ["k2": "v2"]]
 var d2: [[String:String]] = [["k1": "v1"], ["k3": "v3"]]

 d1 = d1.filter { (element) -> Bool in
   return !d2.contains(element)
}
```

[Screenshot of code and exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN6wZ.png)

When I instead use something like...

```
d1 = d1.filter { (d1_entry) -> Bool in
  for d2_entry in d2 {
    if d2_entry == d1_entry {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

All works fine, but... that's very kludgy and verbose for what seems like it should be equivalent logic...?

I know I'm missing something really obvious / fundamental here, but I'm not sure what / where / why.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't implement the contains() closure correctly it should be like this:

```
var d1: [[String:String]] = [["k1": "v1"], ["k2": "v2"]]
var d2: [[String:String]] = [["k1": "v1"], ["k3": "v3"]]

 d1 = d1.filter { (element) -> Bool in
   return !d2.contains({ (element) -> Bool in
        // Define condition
   })
}
```

Comment: Wow - didn't realize I had to implement the contains closure for a dictionary, but I guess that makes sense.  My bad.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Contains requires a closure. Try this.

```
 return !d2.contains {$0 == element}
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the help